# Fetch file from localhost without web server

Tags: python, webserver, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to fetch file from localhost without web server asynchronously. Seems that it is possible to do using file:// scheme. The following code sample is taken from documentation, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        html = await fetch(session, 'file://localhost/Users/user/test.txt')
        print(html)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

How to make it work?

The one way I see is to use "curl file://path" in separate thread pool using run_in_executor, but I think there should be a way to fix code

Comment: If  you need to obtain the contents of a local file, can't you just do it in Python without any special libraries, e.g. `html = open('Users/user/test.txt').read()`? If the file is not very large, you probably don't need to make it async.

Comment: Files are big and it is an idea to make it asynchronous not to block other asynchronous tasks

Comment: Then I'd recommend doing that, just in a function invoked through `run_in_executor`. It's literally three lines of code, and you don't depend on any external program. Another option is the aiofiles library, but that also uses threads under the hood and can end up being less efficient than the "obvious" code.

Comment: @user4815162342, yes, I see, thanks. I thought that using run_in_executor is the best choice here, and maybe it is the only one. Thanks a lot. And the last question regarding it: should I use created event loop for run_in_executor or should I create another one for it?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, "creating a second event loop" is almost never the right way to use asyncio. In case of `run_in_executor`, the whole _point_ of that function is to integrate legacy sync code into your event loop - if you created another event loop just for `run_in_executor`, you wouldn't be able to await it! But what might make sense, and maybe what you intended to ask, is creating another _executor_ (thread pool). The executor provided by asyncio when you pass `None`  as the first argument of `run_in_executor` works just fine, so that's not necessary either. See the answer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to obtain the contents of a local file, you can do it with ordinary Python built-ins, such as:

```
with open('Users/user/test.txt') as rd:
    html = rd.read()
```

If the file is not very large, and is stored on a local filesystem, you don't even need to make it async, as reading it will be fast enough not to disturb the event loop. If the file is large or reading it might be slow for other reasons, you should read it through `run_in_executor` to prevent it from blocking other asyncio code. For example (untested):

```
def read_file_sync(file_name):
    with open('Users/user/test.txt') as rd:
        return rd.read()

async def read_file(file_name):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    html = await loop.run_in_executor(None, read_file_sync, file_name)
    return html
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me very much. I see now